# Cannot Run and Preview Android Jetpack Compose jcenter wouldn't work

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I want to learn android compose. but, I have a problem when I want to run my project, I am getting this error.

Please, help me. I can't figured out it.

many other people in forums suggest me to use jcenter() but, for me still wouldn't work. am i doing wrong ? [gradle with jcenter()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xd8N.png)

This is my gradle configuration.
[Gradle Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfXX3.png)

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable-jvm:0.3.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-collections-immutable-jvm/0.3.3/kotlinx-collections-immutable-jvm-0.3.3.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-collections-immutable-jvm/0.3.3/kotlinx-collections-immutable-jvm-0.3.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta01 > androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.0.0-beta01

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfxbd.png)

Answer (score 0):

`org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable` is still available on jcenter. Here's an issue regarding this: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable/issues/96

Add `jcenter()` to your `repositories` block:

```
repositories {
    ...
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: thanks. but, still won't work on me :(